# where can I download ECHAM climate model data?

Tags: climate-models, open-data

Is there any website where can I download ECHAM climate model data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Where to find the data

The German Climate Research Center ([DKRZ](https://www.dkrz.de/up), Deutsches Klimarechenzentrum) hosts the Word Data Center for Climate ([WDCC](https://www.dkrz.de/up/systems/wdcc)). You can search the WDCC via the CERA Database ([cera-www.dkrz.de](https://cera-www.dkrz.de/)).

Looking for ECHAM provides you with several sets of ECHAM model results: [here](https://cera-www.dkrz.de/WDCC/ui/cerasearch/q?query=ECHAM&page=0&rows=50). You get at least the ECHAM data for the second to fourth IPCC assessment reports and some more data sets.

You need to have a login. It can be easily created.

## Information on the structure of the data at CERA

You have **projects**, **experiments**, and **data** (sets).

*Projects* contain overall information on the model setup, on the data producers, and on the validation.

One *experiment* can summarize several *data* sets. For a coupled climate model this could mean, that the physical ocean, the biogeochemical ocean, the meteorology, and the atmospheric chemistry are saved as individual *data* sets, which are than summarized as one *experiment*.

Experiments can have a doi ([digital object identifier](http://www.doi.org/)). Thus, they are easily citeable in scientific publications and long-term available.

## Access data at the WDCC

You can directly download data via the web-interface. As an alternative, you can use [jblob](https://cera-www.dkrz.de/WDCC/ui/cerasearch/info?site=jblob), which is a command line utility for downloading data from the WDCC. Jblob also has some options to pre-process data on the DKRZ servers prior to download it -- which might reduce your file size. For both access pathways you need to have a valid login.